# How to tackle cold?

Tags: meditation, meditation-practicalities, meditation-insight, meditation-effects, meditation-hindrances

Simple question -- how to tackle cold feeling during winter **through meditation** other than clothes or anything?

Asking for specific meditation details with insight for tackling cold without any tantra or mantra or yantra.

- **What** will be sensations in various parts of body?
- **What** will be various body-parts movement during meditation(other than shaking)?
- **What** will be the thoughts?
- **Will** one have to maintain some pressure within body?
- **What** will be the side effects or hindrances, if any?

All the **minute details** which can be **generalized to everyone**.

Don't write answers with advice like, "think to be born in cold countries..."... **Here coldness/enviornment refers to the point where meditator will have the need to wear woolen clothes...!**

If you have any authoritative (**gautama the buddha's only**) source for **meditation** on such, can give that -- but otherwise looking for **specific practical experience**.

**Theorist may consider it a challenge, if they haven't experienced**

Be Happy,
Metta

Comment: How cold are you asking about -- what temperature, how much wind, wearing what clothing, and for how long?

Comment: @chrisw already edited, read question properly, again.

Comment: When I asked, "how cold?", I meant, "what temperature?" The other questions -- like "how much wind", and, "for how long", are relevant too, I think. Your edit i.e., "cold enough to need to wear woollen clothes", didn't mean much to me. You don't have to answer but I thought it relevant to ask.

Comment: Last comment for @ChrisW on this particulat Q&A thread:: Nope! Thinking in `wrong` direction. These 2 questions are a challenge and greatest contribution to buddhists/truth-seekers, till now on internet. Good luck(if luck exists)!.

Comment: @Ego Breaker.Such a very ego-full comment...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is "too open-ended" (as described in the [Moderation policies for Questions](https://buddhism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1572/254)).

Answer (score 2):

Buddhists usually put on warm clothes if they’re feeling cold. If the feeling persists, consider talking to a physician.

Answer (score 1):

I'm inclined to agree with Erik.

Here's Ven Yuttadhammo, who is Canadian and in Canada -- [Ask A Monk: Avoiding Cold](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=10LLeH9fp3w) -- saying that you might wear a hat "as a matter of course".

I think it's a matter of learning (or being taught) what the body can tolerate -- physical problems include (depending on how cold it is), hypothermia, chilblains, eventually frostbite.

I used to bicycle to and from work, just over an hour each way, in Toronto, year-round. And they were some of my favourite hours of every day, but a slightly extreme/unusual practice in winter and doing it (subzero and wind and sometimes wet for an hour twice a day every day) did depend on wearing winter gloves and boots.

Can I say, "don't be stupid"?

Every Canadian must learn to live with cold (and to dress appropriately). Winter there even in the south might have a daytime high of -10°C for months on end -- but life goes on, for everyone, you go out to go to school or work or exercise.

One danger is that stupidity (or "confusion") is caused by hypothermia -- i.e. if you do become hypothermic you might be too stupid to realise that and do something about it. Once I spent a week mountain-hiking with a school group in spring, and then we were told to watch out for our "[buddies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_system)" -- we were told that if they stop being able to talk sense, that if they get angry, then perhaps they're hypothermic and we should act on that.

Another thing to know, I guess, is that "feeling cold" is a kind of a good thing -- where it becomes dangerous is if you lose sensation in a body-part -- usually extremities like the ears or toes.
Ditto if you [feel overheated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothermia#Paradoxical_undressing) when you're not (not that I have experienced that extreme personally).

If you're interested the first place I feel cold is my ribs -- on either side, left and right, and level with my heart. There's no fat there, under the skin. A typical meditation posture might have your elbows down and upper arms against your sides protecting that area.

I reckon you ought to regulate your [core temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_body_temperature#Core_temperature) -- for health reasons, that's only sensible and a "middle way" practice -- and that skin temperature (and/or skin being wet) doesn't matter as long as you avoid chilblains and frostbite.

Comment: This answer is also spam, not from a meditator. Just trying to show ego&stupidity by saying OP to be stupid. Householders are not invited.

Comment: I'm not calling you stupid. I'm warning that becoming genuinely cold is a cause of stupidity -- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypothermia#Paradoxical_undressing) -- "This typically occurs during moderate and severe hypothermia, as the person becomes disoriented, confused, and combative" -- and causes impairments to the body's feeling the cold.

Comment: I find this type of unsubstantiated 'stupidity, not a meditator and ego' allegations very rude. Especially from a new account... Looks like a troll/puppet account really. In general i don't see why such patronizing statements are tolerated.

Comment: The mods do so much work here and definitely shouldn't have to deal with this crap. It's just abuse and harrasment. Id even bet on whose account it is if id get 2:1

Comment: @sigh... I don't really feel abused, I don't think, so don't worry? though I would have deleted the comment if it were addressed to another user. I guess I might recognise which other user account this one is like, though it might not be the one you're thinking of (try not to hold a grudge, eh). I can see my answer's saying, "don't be stupid", might look insulting to the OP (sorry). Perhaps it's a fair comment then and gave me a chance to clarify what I meant to say -- that even a small drop in core body temperature is dangerous, stupefying, and a matter of physics and physiology.

Comment: Also that "shaking" ([aka shivering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shivering)) generates heat (from the muscles). So I imagined (at the risk of exaggerating) that if a meditator tried to pacify that shiver reflex or refuses to *do* something to stay warm then a body might only get colder and more quickly (perhaps even at not-especially cold air temperatures). It might be an altered state but IMO not a sane one, ditto if you're solitary and without a buddy.